# Do the Community Day Heads Still Drop?

Tags: borderlands-2

Does anyone know if the community day heads still are drop able? I know they are unobtainable trough shift anymore, but do they still drop for bullymong piles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they do still drop. I got a "REACH FOR THE SKIS" head for Krieg a few days ago.